# Searching in JavaMail - how to make it happen server side?

Tags: search, gmail, jakarta-mail

I think I'm missing something about how to search in JavaMail.

1. Download empty messages from a folder
2. Create a new SearchTerm that matches your results
3. Filter (yourFolder.search) the results using your search term.

This works.  But - why do it this way?  If I'm using javamail to connect to something like gmail, the search isn't being executed server-side, and it doesn't seem like there is any advantage to using the whole javax.mail.search.SearchTerm constructs in terms of efficiency or reducing the amount of data that needs to be sent over the network...

I don't see any way that executes a search on the server side and returns a list of matches.  Any ideas?

EDIT: Including pseudocode of what I'm doing now, which doesn't execute any search on the server-side.  Even if I converted this to use **SearchTerm** it still wouldn't be doing anything server-side, right?

```java
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "gimaps");
final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
final GmailSSLStore store = (GmailSSLStore) session.getStore("gimaps");
store.connect(ADDRESS, PASSWORD);
final GmailFolder allMailFolder = (GmailFolder) store.getFolder("[Gmail]/All Mail");
allMailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
final Message[] allMessages = allMailFolder.getMessages();
System.out.println("Messages:" + allMessages.length);

FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
allMailFolder.fetch(allMessages, fp);

for (final Message message : allMessages) {
  final Address[] addrs = message.getFrom();
  if (addrs != null) {
    for (final Address addr : addrs) {
      if (addr.toString().toLowerCase().contains("george")) {
        System.out.println(addr.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something wrong, but you haven't provided enough details about what you're doing for us to know what you're doing wrong.

Are you using IMAP?

Show us some code and the debug output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching in an IMAP folder using the predefined `SearchTerm` implementations, it will try to perform the search on the server. Look at the implementation of `SearchSequence.generateSequence`. In your example you would probably want to use `FromStringTerm`.

If you're using the gimap provider, you can also use Google's IMAP extensions, which include the `X-GM-RAW` search attribute, allowing you to search exactly like in the Gmail web interface. The java implementation is in `GmailRawSearchTerm` and **only** works server-side.